# How to display an image stored in SQL Server field using image data type?

Tags: php, sql-server

Good day

I'm trying to show an image using DATA URIs and encoding a string in base64 as shown below:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php base64_encode($FOTO) ?>" />
```

The image (JPG) is stored in the database in this way:

[image: structure of the table]

[image: stored image]

The problem is that using that DATA URI, it does not show the image on the screen. I don't know the error or if I have to do something different to be able to show that stored image.

[image: HTML source code]

[image: Image not created :(]

Is there any other way to display these images stored in SQL Server?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You should stop using the image datatype. It has been deprecated for well over a decade now in favor of varbinary(max). I can't help you with php though.

Comment: Are you sure the value in db is `base64`? I don't think so

Comment: Thank you very much @SeanLange, unfortunately I can not make changes in the structure of the database, and I wanted to know if there is any approach to solve that problem.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr In fact, the only thing I know is that it is a jpg file stored in the database

Comment: It is stored as a byte array. I have no idea how you handle that in php but surely there are thousands of example of this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in db is not base64, you need to convert this hexadecimal data to base64. Php, as I know doesn't have a direct function to do that but it can be achieved with `pack()`. I leave it to you as homework to study this function.

Convert the data from db to base64 like:

`$fFoto = base64_encode(pack('H*', $foto));`

Then pass this `$fFoto` to image `src` like you are already doing.

`<IMG src="data:image/jpeg; base64, <?php echo $fFoto; ?>" />`